# Add existing Azure Function to workspace in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs-code?tabs=csharp) on how to create and track Azure Functions, with the [Azure Function Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurefunctions) in VS Code. I cannot however, find any guide on how to add existing functions, so they become tracked by the extension. It just says:

> Initialize Project for Use with VS Code...

As you can see here:

[image: Screenshot from the Azure Function VS Code extension.]

If I click it, I get prompted to overwrite a task, but nothing happens if I do so. The function is actually able to run in debug, so it seems to be a tracking issue with the extension.

Anny clues on how to solve this?

Comment: Click fn + f5 or run > Debug to run the function and check if the local function is running in your vs code? Is Azure Functions core tools installed in your local system?

Comment: I am able to view my function successfully like here - https://i.imgur.com/VytwlzK.png

Comment: Thanks for you tip @SiddheshDesai. I did just that, with no luck. Turns out I had to press the "Refresh" button first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments for helping me clearing this out. I need to do two things:

1. Click the "Refresh" button above the list (see screenshot)
2. Run the function host in debug mode (F5)

[image: Screenshot indicating the refresh button location.]